# AWS CDK Step Function Task - Include list of objects in DynamoPutItem task

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to use the [DynamoPutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.DynamoPutItem.html) task to put an entry which includes a **list** of **objects** as one of its attributes. I can't find any examples of this being done online so I'm wondering if it is even possible?

This CDK [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17375) seems to be talking about the same thing but that won't work for me, I'm wondering is that only good for lists of strings not objects?

Here is a simplified example of an item I'm trying to put to DDB:

```json
{
  'someKey': 'This will be fine',
  'anotherKey': [
    {
      'ohoh': 'This object and the list it belongs will cause an error'
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried numerous combinations of [DynamoAttributeValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.DynamoAttributeValue.html) and [JsonPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.html) to no avail :(

Here is an example of some code that I've tried:

```
new DynamoPutItem(this, 'some id here', {
  item: {
    // this will be fine
    someKey: DynamoAttributeValue.fromString(JsonPath.stringAt('$.someKey'),
    // this will cause an error
    anotherKey: DynamoAttributeValue.listFromJsonPath(JsonPath.stringAt('$.anotherKey')),
  },
  table: myTable,
}
```

and the error it throws:
`The field "ohoh" is not supported by Step Functions`

Answer (score 0):

If I read the docu [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.DynamoAttributeValue.html#static-listwbrfromwbrjsonwbrpathvalue) it seems like you need to use:

```
DynamoAttributeValue.listFromJsonPath(value: anotherKey)
```